# Consider the function $f(z)=1/z$ on the annulus $A=\{z \in \mathbb C : 1/2 < |z| < 2\}$. Which of the following is /are true?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a question asked in my exam. I am unable to understand how to approach such problems.

**Question:** Consider the function $f(z)=1/z$ on the annulus $A=\{z \in\mathbb C : 1/2 < |z| < 2\}$.  Which of the following is /are true?

$(1)~~$ There is a sequence $\{P_n(z)\}$ of polynomials that approximate $f(z)$ uniformly on compact subset of $A$.

$(2)~~$ There is a sequence $\{R_n(z)\}$ of rational functions, whose poles are contained in $\mathbb C\setminus A$ and which approximate $f(z)$ uniformly on compact subset of $A$

$(3)~~$ No sequence $\{P_n(z)\}$ of polynomials approximate $f(z)$ uniformly on compact subset of $A$.

$(4)~~$ No sequence $\{R_n(z)\}$ of rational functions whose poles are contained in $\mathbb C\setminus A$ approximate $f(z)$ uniformly on compact subset of $A$

Comment: I edited your math, can you please confirm that this is what you intended (especially the subscripts on the sequences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is false. If $\gamma\colon[0,2\pi]\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is defined by $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$, then $\int_\gamma P(x)\,\mathrm dz$ for every polynomial function. Therefore, if there was such a sequence $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of polynomial functions, we would have $\int_\gamma\frac1z\mathrm dz=0$, which is not true.
2. Sure it's true. Just define $R_n(z)=\frac1z$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$.
3. True (see answer to question number 1).
4. False (see answer to question number 2).

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your response. One request will you please elaborate  answer of first option. I didn't get it properly.

Comment: Sure. I'm just using this fact: if $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly in each compact to a function $f$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\gamma f_n=\int_\gamma f$. But if $P$ is polynomial, then $P$ has a primitive and therefore $\int_\gamma P=0$. It would follow that $\int_\gamma\frac1z\,\mathrm dz=0$. But this integral is, in fact, equal to $2\pi i$.

Comment: Thanks sir Now I got this one.  Sir is there any generalization of this idea, do we have a class of function which can be always approximated by sequence of polynomials ?

Comment: I suppose that you might find [Runge's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_theorem) interesting.

Comment: thank you very much sir.

Comment: Sure sir I forgot  sorry

Comment: Sir may I ask you again a question regarding this?  If in place of 1/z we take a function for which integration on |z|=1 is zero then what can we say? e.g. we take f(z)=e^z then what can we do?

Comment: @PrakashNainwal I don't know the answer for the general question, but in the case of the exponential function, it's easy: it's the limit of its Taylor polynomials centered at $0$: $P_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{z^k}{k!}$. This holds for every entire function, in fact.

Comment: Okay sir but here 1/z is also entire in 1/2<|z|< 1. It means this uniform approximation of f(z) by polynomial depends on the  singularities of f outside of given domain. Am I right? Means Just being entire in given domain is not enough

Comment: @PrakashNainwal An entire function is an analytic function from $\mathbb C$ into itself. The domain of $\frac1z$ is not $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Okay sir thanks for your all responses.